# Spring JPA Unidirectional Ont To Many entity mapping giving error (deserialize)

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Hi I am gettinn 'could not deserialize' error while trying to query for an entity with oneToMany mapping in spring jpa.

My Entities

WebForm.java

```
package com.globalfoundries.partshub.persist.entity.admin;



@Entity
@Table(name = "FORM_PROPERTIES")
public class WebForm  implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8883246076117334766L;

/**
 * 
 */


@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "class", nullable = false)
private String className;



@Column(name = "FIELD", nullable = false)
private String field;

@Column(name = "DISPLAY_NAME")
private String displayname;


@Column(name = "type")
private String type;

@Column(name = "length")
private String length;

@Column(name = "visible")
private String visible;

@Column(name = "required")
private String required;

@Column(name = "list", nullable = true)
private BigDecimal list;

@Column(name = "display_order", nullable = true)
private Integer displayOder ;


public Integer getDisplayOder() {
    return displayOder;
}

public void setDisplayOder(Integer displayOder) {
    this.displayOder = displayOder;
}

@Column(name="searchable")
private Number searchable;
public Number getSearchable() {
    return searchable;
}

public void setSearchable(Number searchable) {
    this.searchable = searchable;
}

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="list_id",referencedColumnName="list")
private Collection<ListEntry> listEntries;

public Collection<ListEntry> getListEntries() {
    return listEntries;
}

public void setListEntries(Collection<ListEntry> listEntries) {
    this.listEntries = listEntries;
}

public String getClassName() {
    return className;
}

public void setClassName(String className) {
    this.className = className;
}

public String getField() {
    return field;
}

public void setField(String field) {
    this.field = field;
}

public String getDisplayname() {
    return displayname;
}

public void setDisplayname(String displayname) {
    this.displayname = displayname;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getLength() {
    return length;
}

public void setLength(String length) {
    this.length = length;
}

public String getVisible() {
    return visible;
}

public void setVisible(String visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
}

public String getRequired() {
    return required;
}

public void setRequired(String required) {
    this.required = required;
}

public BigDecimal getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(BigDecimal list) {
    this.list = list;
}   
}
```

ListEntry.java

```
package com.globalfoundries.partshub.persist.entity.admin;

@Entity
@Table(name = "LIST_ENTRY")
@Embeddable
public class ListEntry implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2833227944278025887L;

/**
 * 
 */


@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "entry", nullable = false)
private String entry;

@Column(name="active")
private boolean active;

@Column(name="list_id")
private BigDecimal listId;

public boolean getActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}

public BigDecimal getListId() {
    return listId;
}

public void setListId(BigDecimal listId) {
    this.listId = listId;
}

public String getEntry() {
    return entry;
}

public void setEntry(String entry) {
    this.entry = entry;
}       
}
```

WebFormRepo.java

```
public interface WebFormRepo extends JpaRepository<WebForm, Long> {

List<WebForm> findByClassNameIgnoreCase(String category);

List<WebForm> findAll();

@Query("select f,al.entry from WebForm f left join f.listEntries al where upper(f.className)=upper(?1)")
List<WebForm> findClassNameIgnoreCasewithList(String category);
```

}

From controller , I am invoking

```
formRepo.findByClassNameIgnoreCase(category);
```

Exception

```
Hibernate: select webform0_.id as id1_0_, webform0_.class as class2_0_, webform0_.display_order as display_order3_0_, webform0_.DISPLAY_NAME as DISPLAY_NAME4_0_, webform0_.FIELD as FIELD5_0_, webform0_.length as length6_0_, webform0_.list as list7_0_, webform0_.required as required8_0_, webform0_.searchable as searchable9_0_, webform0_.type as type10_0_, webform0_.visible as visible11_0_ from FORM_PROPERTIES webform0_ where upper(webform0_.class)=upper(?)
2016-07-25 12:24:44.196 ERROR 5920 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.r.exception.ExceptionHandlerAdvice   : Unhandled exception
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:314) ~[spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225) ~[spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:436) ~[spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.findByClassNameIgnoreCase(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.globalfoundries.partshub.controller.SearchController.searchForm(SearchController.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:52) [spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:262) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:306) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2969) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1696) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1628) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1515) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:726) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:953) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:114) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:462) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
... 82 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2353) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2822) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:805) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:301) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:328) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
... 126 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a bidirectional mapping. You're just not defining it properly. In `ListEntry`, you have:

```
@Column(name="list_id")
private BigDecimal listId;
```

This is the other side of your mapping. The mapping should probably be changed to:

WebForm:

```
// remove listId and listEntries properties
@OneToMany(mappedBy="list")
private Collection<ListEntry> list;
```

and:

```
@JoinColumn(name="list_id")
@ManyToOne
private WebForm list;
```

If `List` is a different object in your model, add it to `WebForm` and map `ListEntry` back to it. As you have a single `List` per 'WebForm' (per the `list` property) and the `List` has some number of `ListEntries`, I'd recommend including it in the domain model, if you're reusing `List`s in multiple `WebForm`s or elsewhere. If not, my example of `WebForm` owning `ListEntries` is correct.

Second, you're trying to map the `list_id` and 'list' columns twice in `ListEntry`. Once from the `JoinColumn` in `WebForm, and once from the`Column`definitions in`ListEntry`and`WebForm`.

I'm not sure that cleaning these up will solve your issue, but your current mappings can't be helping the situation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried above suggestions and still facing same issue.  one thing what I observed is , generated query is not using any joins. "select webform0_.id as id1_0_, webform0_.class as class2_0_, webform0_.display_order as display_order3_0_, webform0_.DISPLAY_NAME as DISPLAY_NAME4_0_, webform0_.FIELD as FIELD5_0_, webform0_.length as length6_0_, webform0_.required as required7_0_, webform0_.searchable as searchable8_0_, webform0_.type as type9_0_, webform0_.visible as visible10_0_ from FORM_PROPERTIES webform0_ where upper(webform0_.class)=upper(?) "

Comment: Hibernate will create multiple, individual queries for related entities by default. This is not an issue related to your problem. After changing, did you update your `@Query`? The stack trace is the same? Are you sure the error is occurring within the `Repository` method (i.e. did you debug into it)?

Comment: yes I updated Query and the and the stack trace is the same. Issue coming while converting result set into Entity

Comment: I am pasting part of trace 
java.io.EOFException: null
 --------com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.findByClassNameIgnoreCase(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]